# Mininet-wifi keeps giving error tx power is negative

Tags: mininet

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller,OVSKernelAP
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

def topology():

    net = Mininet(controller=Controller, link=TCLink, accessPoint= OVSKernelAP)
    print "***Creating nodes"
    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint('ap1', ssid='ssid-ap1', mode='g', channel= '1', position= '25,50,0', range='35')
    ap2 = net.addAccessPoint('ap2', ssid='ssid-ap2', mode='g', channel= '6', position = '75,50,0', range='35')
    sta1 = net.addStation('sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', ip='10.0.0.1',position='50,50,0')
    sta2 = net.addStation('sta2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2',position='40,50,0')
    c1 = net.addController('c1', controller=Controller)

    #print "*** Enabling assciation control (AP)"
    #net.associationControl('ssf')

    print "*** Configuring wifi nodes"
    net.configureWifiNodes()

    print "Creating Links"
    net.addLink(ap1, ap2)
    net.addLink(ap1, sta1)
    net.addLink(ap2, sta2)

    print "Starting Network"
    net.build()
    c1.start()
    ap1.start([c1])
    ap2.start([c1])

    """Plot Graph"""
    net.plotGraph(max_x=100, max_y=100)

    print "****Running CLI"
    CLI(net)

    print "****Stopping Network"
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    topology()
```

When I run the code I keep getting error:

***Creating nodes

*** Configuring wifi nodes

*** Error: tx power is negative! (-15)

This is the basic code I found in the tutorial and I am stuck at this, I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will work if you remove the range parameter and use `net.plotGraph(max_x=100, max_y=100)` just before net.build().

Comment: Ramon, thanks it works.However, if I want to assign range to an AP is it possible? I want to design in such a way that some AP has larger coverage and some has less

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, you have to configure the propagation model, because the tx power cannot be negative. When you set the range, tx power is automatically calculated.